# Display none !important not working in email when viewed in Chrome

Tags: css, email

I have a autoresponder email that automatically adds content to the email that a user receives. I have styles to hide the content and this works in Outlook and in Gmail when viewed in Firefox but not Chrome or IE. Also when viewing in Gmail in Firefox if I refresh the page, the fields are no longer hidden.

This is the code that I want to hide that is displaying in gmail when I use inspect element:

```
<div id="m_-1227767118273686484surveyContainer" class="m_-1227767118273686484surveyContainer">
```

I tried adding the following:

```
div[id$="surveyContainer"] {
display: none !important;
}

div[class$="surveyContainer"] {
display: none !important;
}
```

Also, when I go to the email in Gmail in Chrome and choose to "view original"

The container is this instead:

```
    <div id="surveyContainer" class="surveyContainer">
```

So I also tried adding

```
#surveyContainer {
display: none !important;
}
```

I have also tried setting a max height and setting overflow to hidden.

This didnt work either? Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be inline styles? If so, that isn't possible for this.

Comment: Can you post the exact HTML you used in the email? I tried something simple like `<div>one</div>
<style>#two {display:none !important}</style>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div style="display:none !important">three</div>` to myself, and the lines one and two were visible on the GMail website in both Firefox and Chrome, and refreshing didn't change anything.

Comment: The content is automatically generated, gmail is adding content to the div ID's so the div id changes each time, The id always contains surveyContainer but gmail adds m-long-random-number-here so unfortunately i cannot use a simple id to select it. I've even tried selecting using div > span but gmail is stripping that code out